# AJAX not executed in form submission

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have the following jQuery ajax to be executed when a form is submitted:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $("form").submit(function() {
    $.ajax("/myapp/rest/customer/created", {
        data : $("form").serialize(),
        type : "POST",
        success : function(data, status, jqXHR) {
            window.location.href = "/myapp/rest/customer/created";

        },
        error : function(jqXHR, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
    return false;
    });
</script>
```

The form is:

```
<form action="/myapp/rest/customer/created" method="POST">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>Username:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="username" name="username"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Customer name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="name" name="name"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Customer DOB:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="dob" name="dob"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br /> <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

After I click "Submit" button, the AJAX code is not executed because it will redirect to `/myapp/rest/customer/created` page no matter whether form submission is successful or not. It seems that the AJAX code is not executed at all. Why is that? Also, if the server sends an error message string to the client-side in case of error, which value should I retrieve in the AJAX code to alert user?

Comment: You forgot `$(document).ready`

Comment: Thanks. That works. But I'm getting a `conflict` alert message (http 409) in case of error, not the actual error string sent from the server. What field can retrieve the actual error message from the server?

Comment: If you're sending a string yourself, that would be a successful ajax call, and the error handler won't be called for that, you have to write that logic yourself in the success handler.

Comment: Now in case of success, I got the `HTTP Status 405 - Method Not Allowed`. It doesn't redirect to the page I specified. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>You need to prevent the FORM's submission default behavior:</strike>

```
$("form").submit(function(evt) {
   evt.preventDefault();
   ...
```

As @adeneo noted, you did include a return false after the ajax call. The problem is that, if your JS code is in the document's HEAD, it gets executed **before** the FORM itself is declared, so your handler is assigned to all the elements of an empty set of forms.

That being the case, the solution is @adeneo's suggestion: invoke your code from a document.ready event handler (good), OR put it at the end of the HTML body (ugly).

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a `return false` at the end there, so that's not the issue ?

Comment: What is ugly about putting it at the end of the `body` or right after the form?

Comment: @Paulpro Putting the scripts in the body does work but tends to develop into messy code as the page size and/or complexity increases. Unless you find a compelling reason not to do so, you're better off having a single entry point that executes once the whole document body elements have been parsed (document ready) or the whole page is loaded (window onload).

Answer (score 0):

In the success callback, you redirect to /myapp/rest/customer/created with

```
window.location.href = "/myapp/rest/customer/created";
```

You need to retrieve the result of your ajax query in data :

> function(**data**, status, jqXHR)

preventDefault and return false are different but in this example are doing the same.

You may wait the dom to be ready too :
http://jsfiddle.net/fZCFs/2/

Comment: I set some error message in my server-side code and send it to front-end AJAX. But I don't see the error message, only the "conflict" alert message because the return status code is 409. The `data` parameter in success callback doesn't contain the error message.

Comment: If the return status code is not 2XX, it's an error and the error callback is fired. In this case, you have to watch in the jqXHR object (jqXHR.statusText ?) - The doc : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR